# Disjoin pandas dataframes based on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm starting to learn DataFrames and I need to convert a table to another following this ideia:

```
DF1:
Engagement    Project_Name   Jan    Feb    Mar     Apr      ...
336           prj_name_1     10     10     10      4
337           prj_name_2     23     10     86      0
338           prj_name_3     10     10     10      10
1001          prj_name_4     14     0      11      11
1002          prj_name_5     11     11     11      150
1003          prj_name_6     101    13     42      11
38            prj_name_7     14     14     14      146

DF2:
Engagement    Project_Name   Month    Value
336           prj_name_1     Jan       10   
336           prj_name_1     Feb       10   
336           prj_name_1     Mar       10   
336           prj_name_1     Apr       4    
...
337           prj_name_2     Jan       23   
337           prj_name_2     Feb       23   
337           prj_name_2     Mar       23   
337           prj_name_2     Apr       23   
...
338           prj_name_3     Jan       10   
338           prj_name_3     Feb       10   
338           prj_name_3     Mar       10   
338           prj_name_3     Apr       10   
...
1001          prj_name_4     Jan       14   
1001          prj_name_4     Feb       14   
1001          prj_name_4     Mar       14   
1001          prj_name_4     Apr       14   
...
```

I need to multiply (or duplicate) the rows by Engagement field and then transform 12 columns (months) to simple two columns in a key-value style (key as the month name and value as the value for that month).

What is a good way to do this using pandas?

Thank you!

Comment: Please comment if the name of the question is wrong. I search for "duplicate rows" or "multiply columns" but always worng results appear.

Comment: I think need `df = df.melt(['Engagement','Project_Name'], var_name='Month')`

Comment: Thank you @jezrael, this function really helped me and the question is really duplicated!